# Re-running SQL Server job if previous run fails

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am having to deploy a change on a legacy SSIS package that has been in production for some time. The developer has not left any documentation for it. The job runs multiple times a day, like 5 times in a day at defined intervals like at 11 am, 3 pm, 6 pm, 9 pm and 11 pm.

It checks for a file from a SFTP location and if the file exists then downloads the file onto the server and loads it onto the table. Now if the file does not exist for the 11 am schedule then it gives a "File does not exist" message and fails but runs automatically after 10 mins to check for the file and after successful load the job is invoked only at the next schedule which is at 3 pm.

Now I had to modify the package so it loads a new column that is added to the file onto the Table. I have deployed the solution onto production and the job is able to load the table fine. It however does not run after 10 mins if "File does not exist". I am not able to understand why it was previously able to run after 10 mins automatically and now its not able to do that.

Any pointers please?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server Agent there is an option to re-run the package at a set interval if the package fails.

[image: SQL Server Agent]